# Ninject.Web.Mvc knows about dynamically loaded Controller but ASP.Mvc doesnt?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have got quite a complex project on the go at the moment, and as part of this I have a MEF layer which purely handles loading of plugins and then the newly loaded plugins expose their routes which are registered with asp.mvc and their controllers which are added to Ninject's bindings.

The problem however comes in when the dynamically added routes are hit (and they are hit, I have checked with route debugger) even with correctly added Namespaces for the plugin within the route. When I say I have added the namespaces I mean like below:

```
var namespaces = new [] { "MyPlugin.Controllers" };
routeCollection.MapRoute(
                    PluginRoute, "plugin/{action}",
                    new { controller = "Plugin", action = "Default" },
                    namespaces);
```

Just to give a little more context to this situation, I am inheriting from NinjectHttpApplication and not doing anything else, no custom controller factories, no custom dependency resolvers, just what Ninject gives me. Then I take the currently active Kernel, give it to the plugins and they register themselves.

Now the routes that are hit do not work, I just get a 404 for any external routes, even though they are hit and the controller is (yes tripple checked) registered with the Ninject Kernel. So I am thinking that although Ninject has the type registered, Mvc's DefaultControllerFactory cannot find the type when calling through to:

```
GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces(string controllerName, HashSet<string> namespaces)
```

One thing that baffles me at the moment though, is that it is not finding it even with the correct namespace... HOWEVER just to prove my hypothisis, if I add the plugin as a reference within the asp mvc project and run it (without changing any code, just the plugin assembly is a reference within the project, so it will end up within the bin directory) it will work. Hits the route and I get the desired output...

So at this point I am wondering if although MEF is hosting the external DLLs, it is not sharing it in some way with the current AppDomain or something... which seems odd...

This is a blocker for me at the moment, so any advice would be great!

Comment: Could you try using a dependecy resolver?

Comment: Where are these plugins located when it all breaks down? Have you tried copying them into the `bin` folder of the project you are running?

Comment: I have had to bite the bullet and write a bit of code to watch the plugins folder and whenever something changes move it into the bin directory. I would love to implement another solution but I dont think one exists, other than getting the assemblies and loading them manually into the AppDomain, but you cannot remove them from there without unloading the whole AppDomain, and if you start to get more than one of them, its all going to get messy...

Comment: Can you provide sample application demonstrating the problem? Either upload it somewhere or send me a mail I will take a look then.

Comment: Sorry for the late response Remo, Will try and copy the core aspects of my current app for you to look at to see if you can see where the problem is, maybe a few days though as im super busy at the moment. Thanks for the responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `DefaultControllerFactory` does not know which type is responsible for handling the requests. You have either to find out why the DefaultControllerFactory does not know about these controllers or provide your own implementation that is able to handle these cases. The problem is definitely more MEF related than Ninject related.

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        Type controllerType = this.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName) ?? this.GetPluginControllerType(requestContext, controllerName)

        return this.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }

    private Type GetPluginControllerType(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        // put your own implementation here
    }
}
```

Another solution is to use Ninject'ss assembly loading mechanism instead of MEF.

Comment: I didnt know Ninject even had a mechanism for that, if it does I would much rather use that than add a new technology to the stack, is it an extension or is there just a pattern for doing so? Any info you could provide on that functionality would be great! I still find it odd that the DefaultControllerFactory cannot find the type... as its in the same AppDomain (to my knowledge) and the type IS registered...

Comment: One of the kernel.Load overloads takes a path to scan for assemblies containing NinjectModule definitions.

Comment: Ah right I am with you, unfortunately I don't think that would solve my *real* problem. I ideally need to be able to dynamically load in a few instances of an interface into a list. i.e IList<IPlugin> Plugins {get;set;}. Currently thats all I use MEF for, so each plugin is loaded into this list at runtime, and others can be added too. However with what you are suggesting I think it is just a way to dynamically get your bindings, which I don't think would satisfy this as it would only bind the list to 1 instance, not fill it up with multiple instances like MEF would.

Comment: @Grofit Not sure I understand exactly what you're saying, but if you're just looking for [multi-injection, Ninject supports that](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection)

Comment: @RubenBartelink wow... it does everything... that there is pretty much what I would need, and I think this then gives me a new question to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds mef related, what happens when you try to instantiate the classes from the kernel directly yourself? If it works you could just create your own controller factory:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;

        return (IController)_kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Although these days with mvc 3 I don't bother with the controllerfactory and go in at dependency resolver level.

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }
}
```

n.b. both need to be registed in application_start respectively (although you'd only use one)

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory(_kernel));

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(_kernel));
```